# Why am I getting 500 code errors and unable to login after 2 years of a working project? (NextAuth)

Tags: next.js, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, vercel, next-auth

I recently posted regarding this in the Next.js discord but wasn't able to find a solution. The issue I'm having has me completely stumped. I'm not sure what the source of the issue is or what further steps I can take to find the source.

**Setup:**
The stack I'm using is Next.js, Firebase, firebase/auth, NextAuth and is hosted on Vercel. I deployed the website about 2 years ago and since then everything has went well. The restricted routes are meant for administration so I put together a pretty janky solution for auth. The Google OAuth provider allowed me to restrict logins to emails with domains not matching ours (only @foobar.com). I ended up using server side hydration to generate the admin portal. Since firebase credentials are accessible to the client I added hardcoded rules to check if the logged in nextauth session's email UID matched any of the the hardcoded ones.

**The bug:**
About 48h ago the website threw a 500 code when attempting to access routes that require authentication. No deployments had been made in 30 days prior to this issue and I haven't experienced any similar scenarios with authentication in the past. After the first incident, I refreshed the page a couple of times and eventually got the page to render and included content. Upon refreshing again after 10 or so minutes, I received the 500 code and haven't been able to access it since.

**Files**

This is how the authentication is handled for all the paths:

```
    import { useSession, getSession, signIn, signOut as nextSignOut } from "next-auth/react"
    import { getAuth, signInWithCustomToken, signOut as fbSignOut } from "firebase/auth";
    import { useEffect } from "react";
    
    const Dashboard = () => {
      const { data: session } = useSession({
        required: true,
        onUnauthenticated() {
        signIn()
        }
      })
    
      const auth = session ? getAuth() : null
        if (!session) {
          signInWithCustomToken(auth, session.fbLoginToken) 
        } 
    
      return (
      <Component />
      )
    }
    export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
      return {
        props: {
          session: await getSession(context),
        },
      }
```

fbLoginToken is assigned to the user's firebase/auth credentials upon creation of a firebase/auth account so I can give admin privileges

`[...nextauth.js]`:

```
    import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
    import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'
    import {admin} from '../../../firebase/adminDB'
    
    const firebaseAdmin = admin.app().auth()
    
    export default NextAuth({
        providers: [
            GoogleProvider({
                clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
                clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
            })
        ],
        jwt: {
            encryption: true
        },
        useSecureCookies: true,
        secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
        callbacks: {
            redirect({url, baseUrl}) {
                return url
                if (url.startsWith(baseUrl)) return url
                // Allows relative callback URLs
                else if (url.startsWith("/")) return new URL(url, baseUrl).toString()
                return baseUrl
            },
    
            async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
                const fbToken = {
                    uid: token.sub,
                    name: token.name,
                    email: token.email
                }
                console.log(fbToken.uid)
                
                firebaseAdmin.getUser(fbToken.uid)
                .then((user) => {
                    !user && firebaseAdmin.createUser(fbToken).then(() => {
                        firebaseAdmin.setCustomUserClaims(fbToken.uid, {admin:true})
                    })    
                })
          return token
        },
            
            async session({ session, token, user }) {
    
                const additionalClaims = {
                    admin: true,
                }
            
                const fbLoginToken = await firebaseAdmin.createCustomToken(token.sub,     additionalClaims)
                .then((customToken) => {
                    return customToken
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log('Error creating custom token:', error);
                })
    
                if (fbLoginToken) {
                    session.fbLoginToken = fbLoginToken
                }
    
                session.token = token
                return session
            },
        }
    })
```

**What I've tried:**
I'm able to access the page and data in dev mode by removing all the authentication checks and logins, so access to the database is confirmed as far as I can tell.

The first thing I tried was routing to all the restricted paths to see if it was a specific path causing the issue, one page allowed me to attempt to login. I'll explain after. Here is the error that showed in the console:

```
     GET https://www.foo.bar/portal 500 (Internal Server Error)
     (anonymous) @ _next/static/chunks/…df504df38854a3.js:1
     p @ _next/static/chunks/…df504df38854a3.js:1
     (anonymous) @ _next/static/chunks/…df504df38854a3.js:1
     (anonymous) @ _next/static/chunks/…df504df38854a3.js:1
     e @ _next/static/chunks/…df504df38854a3.js:1
     a @ _next/static/chunks/…df504df38854a3.js:1
     Promise.then (async)
     e @ _next/static/chunks/…df504df38854a3.js:1
     a @ _next/static/chunks/…df504df38854a3.js:1
```

In addition I found this error in my Vercel logs every time I attempt to login:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'fbLoginToken')`

```
     at Dashboard (/var/task/.next/server/pages/portal.js:56:92)
     at d (/var/task/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:33:498)
     at bb (/var/task/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:16)
     at b.render (/var/task/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-    server.node.production.min.js:42:43)
     at b.read (/var/task/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:83)
     at exports.renderToString (/var/task/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:52:138)
     at Object.renderPage (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:662:46)
     at Object.defaultGetInitialProps (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:332:67)
     at Document.getInitialProps (/var/task/.next/server/pages/_document.js:31:20)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/utils.js:75:33) {
     page: '/portal'
     }
     Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason
     Runtime.ExitError
```

For one of the paths `/portal/deals` I'm for some reason able to attempt to login but I get re-routed to the same login page. The authentication flow is written identically to the other paths too. This set of error occurs in the console after clicking on the login button:

`[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR]  https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error Failed to fetch {error: {…}, url:     '/api/auth/providers', message: 'Failed to fetch'}`

```
    error   @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    n.<computed>    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    p   @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    e   @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    u   @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    e   @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    a   @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    e.fetchData @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    p   @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    e   @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    a   @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    D   @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    p   @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    e   @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    a   @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    e.signIn    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    onUnauthenticated   @   deals-e46d613a1ec08a56.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Ui  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    t.unstable_runWithPriority  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Ql  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Fi  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    bi  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    (anonymous) @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    t.unstable_runWithPriority  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Ql  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Yl  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Kl  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    hi  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    zo  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    (anonymous) @   deals-e46d613a1ec08a56.js:1
    (anonymous) @   0c2b6648-50e9ec590ad7383a.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    registerStateListener   @   0c2b6648-50e9ec590ad7383a.js:1
    onAuthStateChanged  @   0c2b6648-50e9ec590ad7383a.js:1
    Me  @   0c2b6648-50e9ec590ad7383a.js:1
    P   @   deals-e46d613a1ec08a56.js:1
    oo  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Wo  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Ku  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Li  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Ni  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Pi  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    bi  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    (anonymous) @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    t.unstable_runWithPriority  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Ql  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Yl  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Kl  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    hi  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    zo  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    (anonymous) @   deals-e46d613a1ec08a56.js:1
    (anonymous) @   0c2b6648-50e9ec590ad7383a.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    registerStateListener   @   0c2b6648-50e9ec590ad7383a.js:1
    onAuthStateChanged  @   0c2b6648-50e9ec590ad7383a.js:1
    Me  @   0c2b6648-50e9ec590ad7383a.js:1
    P   @   deals-e46d613a1ec08a56.js:1
    oo  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Ku  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Li  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Ni  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Pi  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    bi  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    hi  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    es  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    (anonymous) @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    ki  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    os  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    t.hydrate   @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    v.default.createElement.callbacks   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    ue  @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    s   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    forEach.e.<computed>    @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    r   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    u   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    K   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    Q   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    s   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    forEach.e.<computed>    @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    r   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    u   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    r   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    u   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    r   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    u   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    r   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    u   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    J   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    t.hydrate   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    2870    @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    r   @   webpack-5b2e41c29753785b.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    r.O @   webpack-5b2e41c29753785b.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    e   @   webpack-5b2e41c29753785b.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
```

`[2024-01-26T22:02:52.612Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.6.1): Connection WebChannel     transport errored: ur {type: 'c', target: or, g: or, defaultPrevented: false, status: 1}`

```
    u   @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    warn    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Ar  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Ct  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    At  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    cr.va   @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    tr  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Jn  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Ce  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    r.Ia    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    r.gb    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Ct  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    At  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Rn  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    r.cb    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    r.Fa    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Tn  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    En  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    r.ha    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    r.send  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    ea  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    be  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    we  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    r.Ha    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    jt  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    Nt  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Dt  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    or.m    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Vi  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    send    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    gr  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    br  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    yu  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Su  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    ba  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    enqueue @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    enqueueAndForget    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    $i  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    setTimeout (async)      
    Qi  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Rr  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Ir  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    auth    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    start   @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    bu  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    mu  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    oc  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    await in oc (async)     
    Wu  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    await in (anonymous) (async)        
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    ba  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    enqueue @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    enqueueAndForget    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    jc  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    ql  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   deals-e46d613a1ec08a56.js:1
    s   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    forEach.e.<computed>    @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    n   @   31-2a727551b222a3d5.js:1
    u   @   31-2a727551b222a3d5.js:1
    (anonymous) @   31-2a727551b222a3d5.js:1
    (anonymous) @   31-2a727551b222a3d5.js:1
    (anonymous) @   deals-e46d613a1ec08a56.js:1
    (anonymous) @   deals-e46d613a1ec08a56.js:1
    Ui  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    t.unstable_runWithPriority  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Ql  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Fi  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    bi  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    (anonymous) @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    t.unstable_runWithPriority  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Ql  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Yl  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Kl  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    ki  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    os  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    t.hydrate   @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    v.default.createElement.callbacks   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    ue  @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    s   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    forEach.e.<computed>    @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    r   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    u   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    K   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    Q   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    s   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    forEach.e.<computed>    @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    r   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    u   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    r   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    u   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    r   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    u   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    r   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    u   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    J   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    t.hydrate   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    2870    @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    r   @   webpack-5b2e41c29753785b.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    r.O @   webpack-5b2e41c29753785b.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    e   @   webpack-5b2e41c29753785b.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
```

`[2024-01-26T22:02:52.613Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.6.1): Could not reach Cloud     Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=unavailable]: The operation could not be completed This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.`

```
    u   @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    error   @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Ir  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    qr  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Kr  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Iu  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    close   @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Ar  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    ba  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    enqueue @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    enqueueAndForget    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Fi  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Ct  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    At  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    cr.va   @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    tr  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Jn  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Ce  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    r.Ia    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    r.gb    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Ct  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    At  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Rn  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    r.cb    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    r.Fa    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Tn  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    En  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    r.ha    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    r.send  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    ea  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    be  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    we  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    r.Ha    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    jt  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    Nt  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Dt  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    or.m    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Vi  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    send    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    gr  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    br  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    yu  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Su  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    ba  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    enqueue @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    enqueueAndForget    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    $i  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    setTimeout (async)      
    Qi  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Rr  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Ir  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    auth    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    start   @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    bu  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    mu  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    oc  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    await in oc (async)     
    Wu  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    await in (anonymous) (async)        
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    ba  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    enqueue @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    enqueueAndForget    @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    jc  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    ql  @   _app-cbdf504df38854a3.js:1
    (anonymous) @   deals-e46d613a1ec08a56.js:1
    s   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    forEach.e.<computed>    @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    n   @   31-2a727551b222a3d5.js:1
    u   @   31-2a727551b222a3d5.js:1
    (anonymous) @   31-2a727551b222a3d5.js:1
    (anonymous) @   31-2a727551b222a3d5.js:1
    (anonymous) @   deals-e46d613a1ec08a56.js:1
    (anonymous) @   deals-e46d613a1ec08a56.js:1
    Ui  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    t.unstable_runWithPriority  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Ql  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Fi  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    bi  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    (anonymous) @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    t.unstable_runWithPriority  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Ql  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Yl  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    Kl  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    ki  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    os  @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    t.hydrate   @   framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js:1
    v.default.createElement.callbacks   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    ue  @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    s   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    forEach.e.<computed>    @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    r   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    u   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    K   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    Q   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    s   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    forEach.e.<computed>    @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    r   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    u   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    r   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    u   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    r   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    u   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    r   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    u   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    J   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    t.hydrate   @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    Promise.then (async)        
    2870    @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    r   @   webpack-5b2e41c29753785b.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    r.O @   webpack-5b2e41c29753785b.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
    e   @   webpack-5b2e41c29753785b.js:1
    (anonymous) @   main-0f26aadb5189b1c6.js:1
```

I've tried changing my node.js version from 18.x to 20.x to 16x and back to 18.x with no change.

I added some console.logs into my `[...nextauth.js]` file to monitor on Vercel's logs and see what I can find. The api does seem to be able to pull my session and console.log it right before I return the session object:

```
    {
    user: {
        name: 'abc',
        email: 'foo@bar.com',
        image: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/abcd'
    },
    expires: '2024-02-25T22:06:57.146Z',
    fbLoginToken: 'longtoken',
    token: {
        name: 'abc',
        email: 'foo@bar.com',
        picture: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/abcd',
        sub: '123',
        iat: 123,
        exp: 123,
        jti: '123'
    }
    }
```

Comment: Also, I've tried on multiple devices and networks

Comment: Update: I was able to get my /portal/customers page to populate with data for a second by spam clicking links to the different paths before I get the 500 code.

Comment: Update: the routes seem to be magically working again after adding some `console.logs`. I have no idea what is happening